# Автообновление программы на cmd

Tags: windows-7, bat

Ребята мне нужна помощь я сделал программу , но я не могу сделать так что бы программа автообновлялась при выходе новой версии.
Не могли бы вы подсказать какая команда для этого служит?

Comment: Наверно -update

Comment: Программа на чем написана? если имеется ввиду *.exe формат, то на bat у вас этого не получится, смотрите в сторону powershell или других скриптовых языков программирования.

Ну либо как вариант, хранить версию программы в txt файле и сверять версию из одного текстового файла и другого (на "сервере"). Если на "сервере" версия более новая, то копировать файлы с перезаписью в свою папку, иначе спокойно завершать работу пакетного файла bat